# Excluding Program.cs from code coverage in .net 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

To exclude my code from code coverage in a .net core webapi project, I apply the `[System.Diagnostics.Analysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]` attribute to the unwanted classes.

Now I would like to exclude Program.cs from my code coverage.  However, in .net 6 I don't know how to apply an attribute to this file because it does not have a class declaration.  Can anyone guide me on how I can apply an attribute to this file?

Comment: _"because it does not have a class declaration."_ - say again?

Comment: C# 10 top-level statements.

Comment: It did.  Thanks gunr2171

Comment: Add program and public static Main to it. Then add the attribute.

Comment: If it is all to do with `ExcludeFromCodeCoverage`, just add a `CodeCoverage.runsettings` file. For local in test options auto detect this file and add `<Source>.*\\Program.*</Source>`. This will exclude Program. cs from your local code coverage, pipeline and sonarcloud coverage as well.

See [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2022)

Comment: This is definitely not a duplicate of that other question which is asking about static variables.

Comment: Hi Wayne, were you able to find a solution for this? If yes, can you pls post it here?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The proposed duplicate does not cover the scope of this question. There is an answer that could cover this question, but it is not the only way to do it. The comment above from Laurent and the answer from Anuraj better answer this question.

Comment: Add this to your Program.cs
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

[assembly: ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you can use attributes, but you can exclude the `program.cs` in the `dotnet test` command - like this.

`dotnet test /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura /p:ExcludeByFile="**/program.cs"`

Comment: Since Program is a partial class I just defined it in my Startup.cs with the annotation;
[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
public partial class Program { }

Comment: @PerryArmstrong but .net 6 and 7 doesn't have Startup.cs